# Use phone gallery for ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, gallery

Hi I'm new to android,

I came from this thread and followed how to use the Viewpager
[How to do Gallery Images swap Left To right bydefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623847/how-to-do-gallery-images-swap-left-to-right-bydefault)

It seems like I'm loading the images from drawable:

```
private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
R.drawable.one,
R.drawable.two,
R.drawable.three
};
```

How do I get the images from the phone's gallery instead?

Comment: Similar...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144783/how-to-access-an-image-from-the-phones-photo-gallery

Comment: you need to [Read Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674634/saving-and-reading-bitmaps-images-from-internal-memory-in-android) and add them to your custom Adapter

Comment: I see, I'll read the other thread and Read Images as well (I have to learn a lot) thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> following function get all image list from gallery

```
    private ArrayList<String> getAllShownImagesPath(Activity activity) {
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
        ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

        cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
        }
        return listOfAllImages;
    }
```